# Using Markdown, how do I center an image and its caption?

Tags: html, css, markdown, center

I want to end up with:

```
Hello there!

      <image>
      This is an image

Hi!
```

Where the image and the text `This is an image` are centered on the page. How do I accomplish this with Markdown?

Edit: Note that I'm looking to horizontally center the image and text on the page.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://dev.to/bdavidxyz/markdown-center-image-39j1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a block container with a defined height, same value for line-height and image with vertical-align:middle;
It should work.

```
Hello there !

<div id="container">
    <img />
    This is an image
</div>

Hi !

#container {
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
}

#container img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Can I use Markdown syntax inside the `div`?

Comment: I think Markdown is not used for positionning

Comment: Oh, I was looking for horizontal centering.

Comment: @Chetan I don't believe you can. Once you go into HTML mode by opening a tag, only HTML goes through until you close that tag, and then the parsing goes back to markdown mode.

Comment: Note: This same method can be used for horizontal centering as well.

Comment: is this supposed to be put in .md directly? the css part seems to get understood as text

Answer (score 60):

I figured that I'd just have to use HTML where I want to horizontally align anything.

So my code would look like this:

```
Hello there!

      <center><img src="" ...></center>
      <center>This is an image</center>

Hi!
```

Comment: The `<center>` element is **deprecated** in HTML4 since 1998. Just use CSS to make it or its wrapper a block element with a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto;` on it.

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean it can't be used. Chetan has given a valid suggestion.   I don't think he deserves his current -12 rating for this comment.

Comment: Seconded, the tag may be deprecated but in this case it is useful.

Comment: Of course it shouldn't be used, that's why "deprecated" exists. A one-liner CSS is the right way to do it, *inline* if you don't want a stylesheet. No reason at all to keep using `<center>`.

Comment: Simple solutions that are deprecated in favor of complicated solutions shouldn't be, imo.  Both should coexist.  Sigh.

Comment: Tip: If you're using bootstrap as well, the .text-center class already exists for you

Comment: Yes, <center> has been deprecated for many years. Yet, you can be sure that browsers will still support it fully in the year 2525.

Comment: This is useful in markdown if you don't want to or don't have access to the CSS style sheet, and is more expressive than typing an inline-style.

Comment: This made my day. In this case important is more if deprecated means just bad practice or its wrong. `<center>` is more appropriate in a markdown language instead of using css as the main intention of a markdown language is to minimize the work you have when writing because you do not want to concentrate all the time on formatting. Otherwise you could do it even in html. And markdown exists because html would be too complicated!

Comment: I have upvoted every comment here along the lines of "deprecated? so what - it is useful"

Comment: FYI - This does not work in gitlab's markdown.

Comment: For gitlab you need to use <div align="center">xxxxx</div>

Answer (score 47):

I think I have a simple solution that will work given that you can define CSS. It also does not require any extensions or HTML!  First your markdown image code:

```
![my image](/img/myImage.jpg#center)
```

Note the added url hash #center.

Now add this rule in CSS:

```
img[src*='#center'] { 
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You should be able to use a url hash like this, almost like defining a class name.

To see this in action, check out my JSFiddle using SnarkDown to parse MarkDown in a textarea - https://jsfiddle.net/tremor/6s30e8vr/

Comment: It worked! But can you explain why the CSS part work? It just set to block and auto margin. No center style. How can it be centered?

Comment: In CSS, when margin: auto is used, an element will center relative to its container.

Comment: pity I didn't find this sooner!

Comment: What a beast! Everybody using HTML in Markdown and then this. Very very nice solution

Answer (score 22):

If you are using [**kramdown**](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#block-ials), you can do this

```
Hello there!

{:.center}
![cardinal](/img/2012/cardinal.jpg)  
This is an image

Hi!

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

In [Mou](http://25.io/mou/) (and perhaps Jekyll) this is quite simple.

```
-> This is centered Text <-
```

So taking that in mind you can apply this to the img syntax.

```
->![alt text](/link/to/img)<-
```

This syntax doesn't work for Markdown implementations that implement only what is documented on [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Answer (score 11):

I'm surprised no one mentioned this way:

```html
Hello there!

<p align="center">

  <img src="">
  This is an image

</p>

Hi!
```

Comment: Can confirm, this works for GitHub READMEs. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 7):

With kramdown (used by githubpages)

```
{: style="text-align:center"}
That is, while there is value in the items on
the right, we value the items on the left more.
```

Or using the response from @(Steven Penny)

```
{:.mycenter}
That is, while there is value in the items on
the right, we value the items on the left more.

<style>
.mycenter {
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: THIS. This is the answer I for some reason painfully spent an hour searching for. (the first one) Thank you @raisercostin. If I could upvote you three times I would.

Comment: This is the answer, Now I know why jewels are at the bottom of the sea :wink:

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution that does not use any deprecated tags or attributes:

```
Hello there!

<img style="display: block; margin: auto;"
src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-print.svg">

<p style="text-align: center;">
This is an image
</p>

Hi!
```