# Jekyll kramdown how to center text

Tags: markdown, jekyll, text-align, kramdown

I am using Jekyll (kramdown), and want to make some text align center.

I found `<span style="">` works for font color and size, but not work for `text-align`.

How can I align some text.

I have tried:

```
<span style="color:gray; font-size: 80%; text-align: center;">Test Text</span>
```

And:

```
-> Test Text <-
```

None of them work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using kramdown block attributes [kramdown block attributes](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes) :

```
Test text
{: style="color:gray; font-size: 80%; text-align: center;"}
```

Comment: This was really helpful. While using kramdown, most of the users are not even aware of how powerful it could be. For a long time, I used HTML tags inside markdown to achieve what kramdown could achieve with block attributes.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just do

```
<center>This text is centered.  And clean.  Amen.</center>
```

as I found here: [Using Markdown, how do I center an image and its caption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912694/using-markdown-how-do-i-center-an-image-and-its-caption)

Comment: It helped! With VIM surround plugin, adding `<center>` is a breeze

Comment: Note that the `<center>` tag has been deprecated for many years, so you should probably avoid it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0):

Although I also agree that Kramdown is best the way to go, another alternative is to replace your `<span>` tags with `<p>` tags.

```html
<p style="color:gray; font-size:80%; text-align:center;">Test Text</p>

<!-- or -->

<p style="color:gray; font-size:80%;" align="center">Test Text</p>
```