# How to center figure caption in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using knitR to import my image into my rmarkdown and I wrote captions using fig.cap. My image is already centered but my caption is always left-aligned. Is there anyway to also align my caption under my image?

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', fig.cap="tmap with multiple data classification methods and classes"}
knitr::include_graphics("tmap01.png")
````

[image: knitr image]

Comment: What type of document are you rendering to? How you can style a document depends in part on that e.g. if you're rendering to HTML, you can set up CSS styling for stuff like this pretty easily. If it's Word, set a reference doc.

Comment: @camille I am rendering to a HTML. I am thinking without adjusting the CSS styling, from rmarkdown are there any options to do it

Comment: There's a bunch of ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3912694/5325862) that are markdown in general, not rmarkdown specifically

Comment: You could also have a glance at [`quarto`](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#caption-locations).

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the document shows that the caption is in a `p` tag with class `caption`, and there's no CSS associated to this class. So you can set some CSS properties to the `caption` class, by adding this CSS chunk (e.g. at the beginning of the document):

````
```{css}
.caption {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```
````